# List late binding functions

Tags: windows, functions, iat

I'd like to identify all late-binding calls made by a windows 32 or 64 executable program. I can take a look at the imported functions through the IAT but I'm unable to list the functions called during a program invocation.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is your friend.

Note that it's almost impossible to find out which libraries/entry points a program uses by static analysis alone, since the strings passed to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` might be obfuscated, i.e. not visible in the binary. `Dependency Walker` catches those calls at runtime, which means a) you need to run the program - which may not be advisable if it's known malware - and b) it still might miss something if you don't execute that path of code. But within these restrictions, it's about the best you can get.

Comment: I really have to thank you, I didn't know that and I can finally inspect a list of calls that the application did (it seemed suspicious at first that the app didn't use any of the calls I thought it did). Thank you!